# Amazon EC2 to S3 transfer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, backup, ec2-api-tools

I wanted to backup my EC2 instance to S3. I downloaded EC2 tools from: http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=351.

I set up environment variables to:

```
EC2_HOME=<EC2 tools directory>
EC2_PRIVATE_KEY=<path to private key generated after I created new X.509 certificate>
EC2_CERT=<path to certificate I created in X.509 Certificate tab>
JAVA_HOME=<path to java jre>
```

When I run command:

```
ec2-bundle-instance -b bucket_name -p bucket_prefix -o access_key i-23084b49 -w secret_access_key
```

I keep getting the message:

```
Client.InvalidInstanceType: Instance i-23084b49 does not support bundling.
```

Do you have any idea why?

What do you recommend as easiest way of backing up EC2 to S3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for why this has been happening is the fact that this particular set of EC2 tools couldn't be used to bundle Linux instances. Installing proper EC2 tools solved the problem.

Comment: What are the "proper" EC2 tools?

Answer (score 0):

you can always use rightscale, the free account offers the bundle option.